# read line textfile and split if it got comma

Tags: c++, split

Textfile content

```
a,b,c,d,
efgh
ijk1
```

I wish to store in array, myArray[]; Expected output will split base on comma:

```
myArray[0] = a;
myArray[1] = b;
myArray[2] = c;
myArray[3] = d;
myArray[4] = efgh;
myArray[5] = ijkl;
```

What I had done

```
string myArray[100];
int array_count = 0;

ifstream file((path+dicfile).c_str());
std::string str;

while (std::getline(file, str,','))
{
    myArray[array_count] = str; // store those value in array
    cout << str << "\n";
    strings.push_back(str);
    array_count++;
}
```

The output of I had done

```
myArray[0] = a;
myArray[1] = b;
myArray[2] = c;
myArray[3] = d;
myArray[4] = efghijkl;
```

Comment: `getline` with those args gets your line until the next comma or the eof

Comment: If the input data is correct, you are missing a comma between the final two strings.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton yup, the style is like that, the final two string will combine together because of no comma between it, but the textfile content initially no comma at there ...

Comment: In that case I'm not seeing the problem - your output is correct no?

Comment: So your requirements are not right: it should split on EOL and on comma.  What about other whitespaces?

Comment: @stefaanv ya! that my requirement, i want split if got comma, and also split on EOL, I dun want whitespaces

Comment: @GeorgeNewton compare the expected outcome and my code outcome and you will know what the problem is

Comment: If you had mentioned the newline requirement, then yes - but if, as per your question, you say you need to split on comma only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is an addition to the original code splitting per line and then splitting that line per comma:

```
string myArray[100];
int array_count = 0;

ifstream file((path+dicfile).c_str());
std::string line;

while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(iss, str, ','))
    {
        myArray[array_count] = str; // store those value in array
        cout << str << "\n";
        strings.push_back(str);
        array_count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: line 7 ; should be write  while (std::getline(file, line, ','))